# Is there a method being called when a user removes my app from iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would like to know if there is a way to know if a user removes my app from his iphone (permanently).

(I would like to handle this kind of event in order to remove it from my DB on my server)

Thank you.

Comment: Does user-provided data really take up that much storage? One kilobyte per person fits neatly on two three-terabyte drives, assuming every human has an iPhone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Answer. No. Your best option is to check for inactivity for x amount of time and assume that means it's deleted.